# Clean interface that supports Callbacks, Promises and async/await

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm in the process of building a small Library that relies heavily on asynchronicity and I'm trying to support NodeJs callback style, Promises and async/await with minimal duplication of functional code.

So, as example take the following ( it doesn't matters what it does)

```
class Someclass{
  constructor(){}

  asyncMethod(someData, cb){
    var commonVar = ''
    if (cb) { // ******* Callback Requested
      doSomething()
      var result=usingCallbacks()
      if (!result) cb('Error')
      cb(null, result)
    } else{ // ******** we should use a promise
      return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        doSomething()
        var result=usingPromises()
        if (!result) reject(err)
        resolve(result)
      })
    }
  }
}
```

So i'm stuck on how to build the async/awit part here. Any ideas?

Comment: A *clean* interface uses promises and nothing else.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "*async/awit part*". You can `await` any promise, if your code returns promises then it'll work with both `.then()` and `async`/`await` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing else is required since `await` can await anything that returns a `Promise` (or something promise-like).

In other words, this should "just work":

```
async useLibFn() {
  await someclass.asyncMethod('foo');
}
```

Under the covers, `async`/`await` are just syntactic sugar for promises.

- `async` causes a function to *always* return a promise.  Basically equivalent to:

  ```
  function someFn() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      try {
        // actual fn body
      } catch (ex) {
        reject(ex);
      }
    });
  }
  ```
- `await` takes some expression and resolves it asynchronously.  If the value is promisey, it waits for the promise to resolve (calls `then()`).  Otherwise, it resolves with the value on the next tick.  Basically equivalent to:

  ```
  Promise.resolve(rval).then(...)
  ```

Comment: So I understand that returning a (correctly built) Promise makes the interface async/await friendly inmediately ?

Comment: @mtsdev Correct.